# How to reduce size of APK in Expo/React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing an app by using react native with expo.
As I am compiling to Apk file. The size goes up to 48mb and after having installed on a device, it goes to 90mb.
Is this normal?
Are there any ways to reduce the size of the app in 2020?
Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you using the bare - or managed workflow ? Interesting doc on the subject : https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/managed-app-size.md

Comment: no i'm not using workflow

Comment: So it all comes down on which assets (images ? video ? sound ?) and 3rd party libraries (Firebase ? other SDKs ?) you're using in your app. Also, for APK, make sure you split your ABI (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits)

Comment: i'm just working on eBook the data store is locally store data into .js file .
noting more and display the table of content on a screen .
the data.js file size 1.64MB .

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to agree with Vinzzz that most of the size will come down to your assets. If you're including things like images or videos make sure the dimensions aren't too big, you don't need a 4k image for example ;)

An app that I've released which is mainly text is also 48mb. This is a normal size for a react-native app unfortunately.